# GetAll: keys and entities guaranteed to be in same order?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, go

I've been using this to load entities and still have the keys available:

```
type Post struct {
    Title    string
    Created  time.Time
    // ...
    key      *datastore.Key
}

func All(c appengine.Context) (*[]Post, error) {
    var p []Post
    q := datastore.NewQuery("Post").Order("-Created")
    k, err := q.GetAll(c, &p)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(p); i++ {
        p[i].key = k[i]
    }
    return &p, nil
}
```

Then it occurred to me to wonder if I could always trust that `k` would be in the same order as `p` (that is, `k[0]` is always the key for `p[0]`)? If I understand it correctly [the appengine-go source](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-go/source/browse/appengine/datastore/query.go#386) suggests that it would, since both slices are build using append. It certainly *seems* to work.

Is what I'm doing safe? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the keys returned by [GetAll](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Query.GetAll) will be in the same order as the values appended to dst.